# POST data from PHP to ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, post

I have a instance of **Apache** and **IIS** running on my server which i need to post data from the `PHP` application to the `ASP.NET` application .. is this action  possible ? ,

- if its **possible** what considerations
  are required ?
- if its not possible what are the
  alternatives ? *(Except -  `Webservices` and `socket programming`)*

because using `web services` or `socket programming` will not provide the overall requirement which i have on head !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this answer on super user

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl

Shows you how to do a post using cURL from PHP.  You can just direct your post to your ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this using Memcache, but I'm not shure thats what you want/need:

I put some data into the cache in PHP and read the same value out in .net, but its a little complicated when it comes to objects, but for basic value types it worked fine...